# Displaying a custom post type title within another loop

Tags: wordpress

I have a Custom Post Type set up called Venues. I'm also using a plugin called Event Organiser, and I want to display the title and link to the venue within one of the Event Organiser templates.

The code is:

```
<?php if( $eo_event_loop->have_posts() ): ?>

<ul <?php echo $id; ?> class="<?php echo esc_attr($classes);?>" > 

    <?php while( $eo_event_loop->have_posts() ): $eo_event_loop->the_post(); ?>

        <?php 
            //Generate HTML classes for this event
            $eo_event_classes = eo_get_event_classes(); 

            //For non-all-day events, include time format
            $format = ( eo_is_all_day() ? $date_format : $date_format.' '.$time_format );
        ?>

        <li class="<?php echo esc_attr(implode(' ',$eo_event_classes)); ?>" >
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a> at VENUE NAME HERE <?php echo __('on','eventorganiser') . ' '.eo_get_the_start($format); ?>
        </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>
```

Where VENUE NAME HERE is, I want the title and link to my custom post type. Might be just something really simple I'm missing, but any help much appreciated.

Comment: Need more info. Does the Venue custom post type already exist? If so, how are you linking the Events with the Venues?

Comment: I actually managed to solve it. Will post answer

Answer (score 0):

I used Advanced Custom Fields plugin and used 'Relationship' field so that I could choose a Venue for each event. Then used this code to bring through the Venue link:

```
<?php $venue = get_field('location_venue'); ?>
<?php foreach( $venue as $venue ): ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $venue->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $venue->ID ); ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

More info available here:

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/tutorials/querying-relationship-fields/